# How do I write my reference for a polygon

Tags: polygons

Given a regular pentagon ABCDE.

```
Angle EAB = x + y
```

I have this formula:

```
x + y = (1/5)(180)(5-2)
```

But how do I write the reference of that?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @EricStucky I mean something like `angle sum of triangle` or `angles at a point` etc.

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't clear things up for me. Are you saying you want a name for the formula?